# How to retrieve parent record field value in javascript?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have written a javascript to retrieve parent record field value .I am unable to get the field value.Here Rfleet_Protocol_Grid_c is a custom object which have lookup to Rfleet_Protocol__c.I want to take the "Rfleet_Protocol__c" object "name".

My Javascript:

```
var protocolname=sforce.connection.query("select Rfleet_Protocol__r.name from RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c where id IN ('" + gridid + "')");

alert('protocolname----->'+protocolname);
```

Example:
This query will return: 
[image]

```
Below box value I want:
```

[image]

Complete code

```
var Gridtyp=('{!gridtype}'); 
var gridid=('{!gridname}'); 

alert('gridname and id>>>'+gridid);

var protocolname = sforce.connection.query("select Rfleet_Protocol__r.name from RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c where id IN ('" + gridid + "')"); 

alert('Protoname---->' + protocolname); 

var records = result.getArray("protocolname"); 

//console.log('-------',records); alert(records[0].Rfleet_Protocol__r.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get record from that variable

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/connection.js")}  
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")} 
var result = sforce.connection.query("Select Rfleet_Protocol__r.Name, Id from RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c WHERE Id = '{!RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c.Id}' "); 
var records = result.getArray("records");   
alert(records[0].Rfleet_Protocol__r.Name);
```

Comment: This solution does not work fine.

Comment: var records = result.getArray("protocolname"); //---> this line have some issue.

alert(records);

Could you please give some other way.

Comment: no luck... I tried the same but it is not properly executing var records = result.getArray("records");

Comment: var Gridtyp=('{!gridtype}');
            var gridid=('{!gridname}');
            alert('gridname and id>>>'+gridid);                        
            var protocolname=sforce.connection.query("select Rfleet_Protocol__r.name from RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c where id IN ('" + gridid + "')");
            alert('Protoname---->' + protocolname);
            var records = result.getArray("protocolname");             
            //console.log('-------',records);
            alert(records[0].Rfleet_Protocol__r.name);

Comment: On RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c  object, we have type pf Grid picklist, so Gridtyp=('{!gridtype}'); will give whick pick list is selected and gridid=('{!gridname}'); will its record Id

Comment: Sorry this also does not work!

Answer (score 0):

@Ratan, This way it worked

```
var Gridtyp=('{!gridtype}');
alert(Gridtyp);
var gridid=('{!gridname}');
alert('gridname and id>>>'+gridid);                        
var protocolname=sforce.connection.query("select Rfleet_Protocol__r.Rfleet_Agreement_Client__r.Rfleet_Country_Code__c from RFLEET_Protocol_Grid__c where id IN ('" + gridid + "')");
alert('Protoname---->' + protocolname);
var records = protocolname.getArray("records");
for(i=0;i<records.length;i++ ){
    var Objrecords = records[i];
    var ccode=Objrecords.Rfleet_Protocol__r.Rfleet_Agreement_Client__r.Rfleet_Country_Code__c;
 }
```

Thank you Ratan for you valuable help